# Can HttpUrlConnection be used for Bearer token/API key authentication

Tags: java, rest, authentication, httpurlconnection

I am evaluating whether to use `java.net.HttpURLConnection` or the `java.net.http.HttpClient` in order to make a REST request. I have a few questions related to `HttpURLConnection`:

1. I have seen code samples that use `HttpURLConnection` to perform **Basic Auth** authentication (with username/password). Can it also be used to perform other types of authentication like Digest Auth, Bearer Token, API Key?
2. I understand that `HttpURLConnection` supports authentication either by setting a request header or via the `java.net.Authenticator` class. If 1. above is true, can both these approaches be used to perform other types of authentication?
3. If I decide to use the `java.net.http.HttpClient` class, does it support all types of authentication?

Any help/code samples will be truly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't it all (or most of it) boil down to the `Authorization` header (or some other custom header per API)? I don't see why it would not work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too, however, I couldn't find anything concrete. Secondly, in addition to setting the request header, the HttpURLConnection supports authentication via the `java.net.Authenticator` class. Again, not sure if that class can be used for other types of authorization methods.

Comment: It’s just a header, any http client will support it. Unless you want to implement the entire OAuth flow, in which case neither support it without an external library. The major difference between the two is that one is traditional, blocking, IO; whereas the newer HttpClient is non-blocking & reactive

Comment: Thank you very much for all your responses. So, as I understand, setting the header should work irrespective of the type of authentication. That makes sense. I had another related question. There is a class called `java.net.Authenticator`. This is used to set a default Authenticator. Basically, to use it, one needs to subclass it and override the `getPasswordAuthentication` method. AFAIK, both HttpURLConnection and HttpClient can use this approach for Basic Auth. Does anyone have any idea if this class can be used for other types of auth?